# large modular arithmetic without powers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How would you find the answer to this

$$111453 \cdot 1812337  \bmod(10)$$

I know how to do it if given powers but don't know how to solve something like this above.

Comment: Use the [Congruence Product Rule](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note : $$111453 \equiv 3 \pmod{10} \ and \ 1812337 \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$$ $$\implies 111453 \times 1812337 \equiv 3 \times 7 \equiv 21 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is equal to:

$111453$ (mod 10) $×1812337$ (mod 10)

Comment: And take mod 10 again if it gives a two digit number.